# Upgrade solution from .net framework 4 to higher ver. 4.7.2; 4.8.VS2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, upgrade

After updating from .net 4 to higher version e.g. 4.5, 4.72 I get the below errors. I updated references etc.

Update was performed manually and with TargetFrameworkMigrator.

```
Error   9209    'Note.Svc.Models.ps_AddNoteBrs_Result' does not contain a definition for 'Modified' and no extension method 'Modified' accepting a first argument of type 'Note.Svc.Models.ps_AddNoteBrs_Result' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Work\Note\Note.Svc\TakeAddSvc.svc.cs 1492    31  Note.Svc
Error   9224    'Note.Svc.Models.ps_AddNoteBrs_Result' does not contain a definition for 'Modified' and no extension method 'Modified' accepting a first argument of type 'Note.Svc.Models.ps_AddNoteBrs_Result' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Work\Note\Note.Svc\TakeAddSvc.svc.cs 1500    31  Note.Svc
Error   9249    'Note.Svc.Models.ps_AddNoteBrs_Result' does not contain a definition for 'Modified' and no extension method 'Modified' accepting a first argument of type 'Note.Svc.Models.ps_AddNoteBrs_Result' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Work\Note\Note.Svc\TakeAddSvc.svc.cs 1513    35  Note.Svc
Error   4777    'Note.Svc.Models.NoteRun' does not contain a definition for 'Checked' and no extension method 'Checked' accepting a first argument of type 'Note.Svc.Models.NoteRun' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Work\Note\Note.Svc\QualityControlTrackingService.svc.cs  511 58  Note.Svc
Error   5712    Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Note.Svc.Models.ps_RerportNote_Result> [c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\mscorlib.dll]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Note.Svc.Models.ps_RerportNote_Result> [c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\mscorlib.dll]' C:\Work\Note\Note.Svc\AddRepSvc.svc.cs  647 42  Note.Svc
Error   5700    Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Note.Svc.Models.ps_ReportAddNote_Result> [c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\mscorlib.dll]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Note.Svc.Models.ps_ReportAddNote_Result> [c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\mscorlib.dll]' C:\Work\Note\Note.Svc\AddRepSvc.svc.cs  646 37  Note.Svc
Error   5838    Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Note.Svc.Models.ps_ReportAddNote_Result> [c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\mscorlib.dll]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Note.Svc.Models.ps_ReportAddNote_Result> [c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\mscorlib.dll]' C:\Work\Note\Note.Svc\AddRepSvc.svc.cs  664 37  Note.Svc
```

Comment: What are `Note.Svc.Models.ps_AddNoteBrs_Result`, `Note.Svc.Models.NoteRun`, `Note.Svc.Models.ps_ReportAddNote_Result`, and `Note.Svc.Models.ps_RerportNote_Result`?

Comment: Report and update procedures.

Comment: Targeting 4.8 with such an old VS version is awfully optimistic.  You're skipping a complete C# compiler rewrite (aka Roslyn), 3 major VS updates and 3 major framework updates.  There isn't much point to it when the Community edition is free.

Answer (score 0):

The project that contains the namespace `Note.Svc.Models` must also have the target framework updated to the compatible version of the project that is using them.

Comment: Yep, what happens after rebuild the solution?